# Can the FAQ be expanded in terms of what's on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, faq-proposed

I've been trying to figure out if a particular question I have is on topic, and haven't been able to find much in the way of guidance. I found the question, [Should the FAQ section on off-topic questions be clarified?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/529/102), but that didn't seem to provoke much of a response.

I realize that the particular section being referred to in the above question is not editable, however, most sites, *especially* sites that are out of beta, have added this information by now.  See for example:

- [Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)
- [Seasoned Advice FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq)
- [Mathematics FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq)
- [Gaming FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)
- [English FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq)

I posed this question in chat and someone implied that it is somehow self-explanatory. I really don't think that it is. For example, which of the following are on topic, and what, if any, are the restrictions on them?

- App recommendations (what's a good X app)?
- App comparisons (which is a better X app, Y or Z)?
- Carrier/network concerns - (is phone X compatible with carrier Y)?
- General network questions (what's the difference between 3G and 4G)?
- General device questions (what's a Candy Bar form factor)?
- Extremely basic questions (how do I use the alarm clock)?
- Obscure tech support questions (error X in app-that-nobody's-heard-of Y)?
- Tactics for Android games (which may or may not be unique to Android)?

That's just off the top of my head. If they're *all* on topic, then that's great - please mention this on the *on-topic* section. If *any* of them are off-topic then it would really help to have a supplementary off-topic section in the FAQ, as many other sites do.

P.S. I also found the entries in [FAQ: "What kind of questions should I NOT ask here?"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/247/102) to be of no help at all. Shopping recommendations, duplicate questions, and speculation questions are all already covered by the boilerplate FAQ and aren't on topic anywhere in the network. The complementary [What kind of questions should I ask here?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/246/102) isn't much more illuminating.

Answer (score 4):

> App recommendations (what's a good X app)?
>   App comparisons (which is a better X app, Y or Z)?
>   General network questions (what's the difference between 3G and 4G)?
>   General device questions (what's a Candy Bar form factor)?
>   Tactics for Android games (which may or may not be unique to Android)?

Off-topic.  Recommendations can get a pass if they're very specific and there's a real problem you're trying to solve, but we prefer "How can I do X?" rather than "Is there an app that does X?"  We only take questions *about Android*, so network/carrier questions are off-topic when they have nothing to do with Android.  Device question are off-topic as well if they're not Android-specific; asking whether an Android phone has a particular feature is different from asking about general cellphone form factors.  Android games are on-topic at gaming.stackexchange.com, not here.

> Carrier/network concerns - (is phone X compatible with carrier Y)?
>   Extremely basic questions (how do I use the alarm clock)?
>   Obscure tech support questions (error X in app-that-nobody's-heard-of Y)?

On topic.  Note the caveat above — your example is on-topic because it's about an Android phone, but carrier/network questions are not on-topic when divorced from Android.  This is all discussed here on Meta, but if the FAQ needs work I'll look into it as soon as I can.

Comment: Agreed, and the top two are definitely covered by "shopping questions", unless they're incredibly specific, and stated more as a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think most of those could be broadly summarized as

> What *problem* are you trying to solve?

and

> ... do you have reason to believe it can be solved with an Android device?

Comment: One could make this type of argument about any of the sites, and yet they all have nuances like this. If I found such a broad definition useful, I wouldn't have asked the question. The "what problem are you trying to solve" in particular doesn't really have to do with scope at all, just constructiveness.